# IMAP4.search by Topic name python

Tags: python, parsing

How to parse emails which contain a file with a specific name, I couldn't parse with SUBJECT because it is empty

Comment: Please present your code, how you tried cope with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it should print the mail id if it has a file with the name that you give.

```py
import imaplib
import email

file_name = ""
server_outgoing = ""
username = ""
password = ""

connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server_outgoing)
connection.login(username, password)

connection.select("inbox")
status, mail_datas = connection.search(None, 'ALL')

mail_ids = []
for mail_data in mail_datas:
    mail_ids += mail_data.split()

for mail_id in mail_ids:
    status, data = connection.fetch(mail_id, '(RFC822)')
    message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

    if message.is_multipart():
        for part in message.get_payload():
            filename = part.get_filename()
            if(filename == file_name):
                print(mail_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem with some modificaitons